# cron a simple test script with debian, screen and ec2

Tags: debian, cron

I am trying to learn cron here (sorry if the question is 101!). So, I have a small test script like so:

```
#! /bin/sh
# /home/admin/js/test.sh
#
SHELL=/bin/bash
source ~/.bashrc

# Some things that run always
screen -d -r myscreen
touch /home/admin/js/testsuccess.txt
exit 0
```

then I do `crontab -e` and add the following entry (I am running debian 7 on ec2):

```
*/15 7-23 * * * root /home/admin/js/test.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

so.. this basically runs every 15 mins within the time specified. The cron seems to run, i.e when I do:

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

I see the output:

```
Oct 26 19:30:01 ip-16-653-987-12 /USR/SBIN/CRON[20700]: (admin) CMD (root  /home/admin/js/test.sh > /dev/null 2>&1)
```

..but I do not see the `touch` new file in the directory. Not sure what is really going on here - any advice to solve this would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the cron entry, your script seems to be working fine.

When you do a plain `crontab -e`, you are modifying the crontab entries corresponding to your user. The format of cron jobs you are using works in the case when you are directly adding crons system wide in `/etc/crontab`

So you can either open the crontab for a specific user using `crontab -u user -e` (since user in your case is `root`, you will need to run this with `sudo`) and enter the cronjob without the user name in it

```
*/15 7-23 * * * /home/admin/js/test.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Or you can add the cron job to system wide cron jobs in `/etc/crontab` instead of using `crontab -e`.

Also note, that you are using `~` in your script which can cause issues, always use complete paths in cron jobs.